# Is there a changelog for JAGS?

Tags: jags

Is there a history of changes for JAGS? I've been looking around the JAGS homepage and sourceforge and found nothing.

Comment: Trying to create a wiki knowledge spot, so that it is easily found next time. Answering our own questions is encouraged even if we know the answer before asking, see [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/166308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no changelog on web or in the release, one must look directly into the source code:

http://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/code-0/ci/default/tree/NEWS